# Submitting an image to Facebook with Javascript and HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I’m going crazy with image upload to Facebook. I’ve tried HTML5 drag and drop methods, Dropzone.js, as well as uploading to my own server before submitting the image via PHP. But the only one I can make work (because of my inexperience, I’ll admit) and that doesn't involve uploading the image to my own server, is by using a HTML form as shown in the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/):

`<form id=“upload_form” enctype="multipart/form-data" action=“https://graph.facebook.com/event_id/photos?access_token=an_access_token” method="POST">
Please choose a photo
<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>
Say something about this photo: 
<input name="message" type="text" value=""><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>
</form>`

I dynamically generate it in Javascript and use `var`’s to fill in `event_id` and `access_token`.

This works fine, so all my permissions and authorising are correct. Now what I’d like to do is handle the response because the browser does as you’d expect when the user clicks `submit` and displays basic text showing the post id and whatnot.

So, I created a button and bound the following to it’s `click` event:

```
var fd = document.getElementById('upload_form');
if (fd) {
  console.log('Sending');
  var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
  XHR.addEventListener('load', function(data) {
   console.log('XHR finished:');
   console.log(data);
 });

 XHR.addEventListener('error', function(data) {
  console.log('XHR ERROR:');
  console.log(data);
 });

 var graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+event_id+'/photos?access_token=' + access_token;
 XHR.open('POST', graph_url);
 XHR.send(fd);
}
```

Once the user has selected an image and clicks my button to execute the above `XHR` completes the send and reports as finished, but Facebook replies with:

`(#324)Requires upload file.`

Please can someone show me where I’ve gone wrong - it’s been a problem for days now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you willing to use jquery and [jquery.ajaxForm plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started)

```
<!-- You form code stay Make sure your form.action url is valid ajaxForm use that as url -->

<form id=“upload_form” enctype="multipart/form-data" action=“https://graph.facebook.com/event_id/photos?access_token=an_access_token” method="POST">
Please choose a photo
<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>
Say something about this photo: 
<input name="message" type="text" value=""><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>
</form>


//your javascript to upload the image togather with message
// put this in a button, not submit button
$('#upload_form').ajaxForm({
    complete: function(data) {
        //process fb response
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Wayne, apologies for the late reply. I'll be trying your suggestion as soon as I can.

Comment: That's the one Wayne! Works first time.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to catch both connections, with and without XMLHttpRequest and see which is the actual difference between both request, I don't actually know what `XHR.send(fd);` does, but maybe it's sending the form content itself, not submitting it?

Fiddler is a very useful tool when connecting to external APIs

Comment: I never got a chance to try Fiddle, but you were almost certainly right about what's actually happening when my button code's clicked.